# Ceasar Cipher w/ modular arithmetic

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, caesar-cipher

I have an additive cipher here that brute forces tests all possible permutations of the fixed ciphertext. It functions just fine but I, for the life of me, can't figure out how to implement modular arithmetic and the formula for decryption. p = ((c - key) % 26) where p is the plaintext value and c is the ciphertext in an array of letters (i.e, A = 0, B=1, etc..)

here is the code

```
public class Problem1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

String guess = "";

String ct = "UOISCXEWLOBDOX"; // ciphertext
    int key;// key to test
    char ch;
    for (key = 0; key < 26; key++) { // for each key value
        for (int i = 0; i < ct.length(); ++i) { // test char
            ch = ct.charAt(i);
            if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
                ch = (char) (ch - key);
                if (ch < 'A') {
                    ch = (char) (ch + 'Z' - 'A' + 1);
                }
                guess += ch;
            } else {
                guess += ch;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("key: " + key + "     " + "Decrypted Message = " + guess);
        guess = "";
    }
}

}// main
```

THIS IS UPDATED CODE FOR MODULAR ARITHMATIC

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
`public class AdditiveCipher {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String guess = "";
    //char pt = 'a';
    String cipherText = "UOISCXEWLOBDOX";
    int key,i,x = 0;

    //array of characters we can use 
    char[] alphabet = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O',
            'P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

    //try each key on the cipher text
    for(key = 0; key < 26; key++)//for each key
    {
        for( i = 0; i < cipherText.length(); i++)//for each letter
        {
             int pt = (cipherText.charAt(i) - key - 'A') % 26;
             guess += (char)pt;
        }
        System.out.print(guess + "\n"); //display each guess
        guess = "";
    }//outer for
}//end main
}//end AdditiveCipher.java`
```

That's my latest attempt after trying for awhile it outputs a ton of boxes. any help with logic would be appreciated, or simply telling my what I'm doing wrong

Comment: BTW once you have the correct mod-26 value you can just do `(char)('A'+pt)` -- the ASCII alphabet used in Java (as a subset of Unicode) has the letters assigned to consecutive codes. OTOH repeatedly adding to a `String` with `+=` (or equivalent) is inefficient; for a toy program like this it probably doesn't matter but before doing any real work learn about `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation for this modulus method of decryption is rather simple, and is done exactly how you have described it in your question. All you have to do is create your array of characters as you described (`A = 0, B = 1, ...`), and do the conversion `p = ((c - key) % 26)` for each character to find the original text. At least, this is how it would work in an ideal world. I'm willing to bet the trouble you are having is with the ASCII values of characters. As you can see [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html), the value `'A'` is equal to the integer 65, and the values of the capital letters increase from there. To compensate for this, add 13 (or `'A'`, as `'A' % 26 = 13`) before performing the modulus division (like so: `p = ((c - key + 13) % 26)`), and you should be good to go. Just to be clear, p is the location in the character array where the original text value for that character is stored, not the actual integer value of the decrypted character. I hope this helped, and good luck with the implementation!

Comment: Just solved the issue, see bottom of post. thank you for the assisstance

Comment: Java `%` is not mathematical modulus but _remainder_ and differs for negative operands; here for example -1 mod 26 is 25 but -1 % 26 is -1. And -1 as a character code is not a valid character.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that a little while ago, but it was too late to change until I got up. I'll modify the post to make the math correct.

Answer (score 0):

THE SOLUTION:::

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class AdditiveCipher 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int key, x, i = 0;
    String guess = "";
    String cipherText = "UOISCXEWLOBDOX";

    //array of characters we can use 
    char[] alphabet =     {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O',
            'P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

//int w = ((cipherText.charAt(7) - 15 - 'A') % 26); // supposed to equal W
    //System.out.println(w);
    //int y = cipherText.charAt(0);

    //try each key on the cipher text   
    for(key = 0; key < 26; key++)
    {
        System.out.println("key is:" + key);
        for( i = 0; i < cipherText.length(); i++)
        {
```

right here...I had to add 26 before the mod to avoid negatives, as well at append whatever is at alphabet[pt] instead of casting pt

```
int pt = (cipherText.charAt(i) - key - 'A' + 26) % 26; 
                 guess += alphabet[pt];             

        }
System.out.print(guess + "\n"); //display each guess
        guess = "";
    }
}//end main
}//end AdditiveCipher.java
```